# Why aren't these ACLs working?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, acl

I'm trying to set ACLs so that the user and group of new files and directories created in the web server directory are owned by the www-data user. I have the exact same ACL on another server and they work fine.

```
andrew@sona:/srv/www$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:www-data:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

andrew@sona:/srv/www$ mount | grep acl
/dev/xvda on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,acl)
andrew@sona:/srv/www$ touch test.txt
andrew@sona:/srv/www$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  3 17:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root     root     4096 Sep  1 19:36 ../
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 andrew   andrew      0 Sep  3 17:14 test.txt
```

Server is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/460262/how-do-i-make-it-so-that-files-created-in-a-directory-have-a-certain-group-owner This may be of help?

Comment: The ACLs above (as far as I'm aware) shouldn't require you to set gid but should have the same effect…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Access control lists* (ACL) provide a fine-grained mechanism to control the *access* to a file/directory. They don't change or define the ownership.

The `default` value defines which ACL a new created file inside that directory should "inherit". These seems to work for `/srv/www`, because your new created file `test.txt` gets some ACL (notice the `+` in the directory listing).

The essentials to accomplish your goal are given in the SF answer linked by @Darius:

```
chmod ug+s /srv/www
```

which sets the *set-user-ID* and *set-group-ID* bit. 
The info manual of coreutils explains this mechanism:

> **27.5 Directories and the Set-User-ID and Set-Group-ID Bits**
>
> On most systems, if a directory's set-group-ID bit is set, newly
>   created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly
>   created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent
>   directory.  On a few systems, a directory's set-user-ID bit has a
>   similar effect on the ownership of new subfiles and the set-user-ID
>   bits of new subdirectories. (...)

Please note the constraint "on a few systems" for the *set-user-ID* bit. Indeed, neither on my Debian nor my openSuSE system the inheritance of the owner works, only the group is propagated. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), this is true for *all* linux systems:

> The setuid permission set on a directory is ignored on UNIX and Linux
>   systems.[[4]](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7727) FreeBSD can be configured to interpret it analogously to
>   setgid, namely, to force all files and sub-directories to be owned by
>   the top directory owner.[[5]](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.1-RELEASE&format=html)

Comment: So when you have `default:group:www-data:rwx` that's the default permissions that should be defined for a file created by members of that group?

Comment: No, that means, that if a file/dir is created, it will have the ACL entry `group:www-data:rwx` -- independent _who_ created the file. Check with `getfacl test.txt` for example, you'll see that all `default` entries of the directory show up.

Comment: Does that not imply then that the group of the file should be www-data? I'm confused as to what function allowing you to specify the group in a default rule has if this is not the case.

Comment: @Prydie Default ACL entries work like normal ACL entries. The `group:www-data:` part specifies who should get the following permissions.

Comment: @Prydie: [This article](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) is a really good introduction to ACL, it surely explains the concepts better than I. (I think this documents was also _my_ start into the world of Linux ACL...)